# What to use, 合繊で or 合繊から？

Tags: usage, particles, particle-で, particle-から

I want to say, that the weaving machine is weaving material on high speed using synthetic fibre. But I am confused, if I can use the combination 合繊【ごうせん】から instead of 合繊【ごうせん】で, so I won't have で twice in my sentence...

Could you please help me understand which, から or で, is better here and why?

> 織機【しょっき】は超速【ちょうそく】でこの合繊【ごうせん】**で**生地【きじ】を織ります【おります】。
>
> ｖｓ
>
> 織機【しょっき】は超速【ちょうそく】でこの合繊【ごうせん】**から**生地【きじ】を織ります【おります】。

Comment: I think there's an issue in your current phrasing, where it could be said a better way. Regardless, you would use 合繊で for this sentence. I might come back and put a full answer if I can figure out why I'm bothered by your current syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both で and から work fine. Using で twice itself does not look odd to me because these two で clearly serve different functions. But in this case から may be a bit easier to understand because it's more explicit about what turns into what. Another simple way to say this is 合繊**を**生地**に**織りあげます. Many compound verbs in the form of ～あげる take `AをBに` and add the meaning of "putting A into B" (e.g, 鍛えあげる, まとめあげる, おだてあげる, 仕立てあげる).

What I'm more concerned with is the mixture of casual and technical words. 織機 is a difficult and technical term, while 超速 is a highly casual and/or manga-like word. If you want to put this sentence rather seriously, you should use 高速で ("high speed") or 超高速で ("super-high speed") instead. 合繊 also looks jargon-like to me, so you might want to replace it with 合成繊維 depending on the audience of this sentence.

> 織機は合成繊維を高速で生地に織り上げます。

Comment: Great explanation and comments, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should say:

> 織機は超速で生地をこの合繊から織ります。

It flows a little better.